# XCode can not open .xcworkspace but AppCode can [cause CocoaPods]

Tags: ios, xcode, appcode

I used CocoaPods in my project, after creating the project it can be opened by both XCode and AppCode correctly, then I wrote the code in AppCode for a few days, today I want to use XCode to open the .xcworkspace file but fail,XCode just displayed  .xcodeproj  file , I can not watch the whole project. Anyone meet the same problem?

Comment: This sounds like an issue you should report on the Jetbrains support forum.

Comment: @Veelian,<br>
if possible, please file a bug report at [AppCode's public tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC) and attach your xcodeproj files - we'll check what's wrong and what could be the reason.

Comment: I fixed the problem by the following steps: 1. I created a new project using CocoasPod 2. I copied the *.xcworkspcec to the old project, then the old project can be opened correctly both by AppCode and XCode. I am not clearly know why this can work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The issue was that all toolbars and panels were hidden. In XCode Went to `View > Show Toolbar` etc. which fixed it.

Might not be the same problem but worth mentioning I think.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I replied to @Anton Makeev above